# How to get query string and rewrite it in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I have queries like this:

```
example.com/folder/?q=keyword
```

Please suggest how to redirect all queries that contain "keyword" as a parameter to other file on server:

```
/folder/core/index.php?id=$1
```

I mean `$1` must be `keyword`

Here is my example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$  /folder/core/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .htaccess in `folder/` directory then try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ /folder/core/index.php?id=%1 [QSA,L]
```